# Emails deleting from email account - office 365

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

I have office 16 - 365 which I have an email account on.

A few weeks back I started randomly getting the same email twice (so if someone sent me an email, I got double of the same message), and now they've all randomly deleted, and when an email comes in, it deletes after a few minutes.

I am using outlook 16, and I have my emails on my phone too. I checked all the rules, and there is none, and I have checked to make sure there were no obvious rules on office 365, and nothing there either.

What could be happening, and what else can I check?

J